# How to accept more than one HTTP object in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
$scope.simulate = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.fileContent = response;
        // simulationData.addData($scope.fileContent);
    },
      function errorCallback(response) {
        $scope.fileContent = response;
    });
}
```

I am trying to make it so that this code runs in a loop and is constantly checking for a new HTTP Object at the specified URL.  I am unfamiliar with Angular.js and would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anuglarjs offers the interval service that you could use here, inject it and use like:

```
$scope.simulate = function() {
  return $interval(function() {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.fileContent = response;
        // simulationData.addData($scope.fileContent);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        $scope.fileContent = response;
    });
  }, 5000); // whatever interval you want here
}
```

then you can cancel the interval by calling `$interval.cancel(param)` where `param` is the return value of the function

like so:

```
var interval = $scope.simulate();
$interval.cancel(interval);
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what the bottom part means about canceling the return value.

Comment: eventually you may wish to stop the interval, that is how you stop it.  I added an explicit edit of what it would look like.

Comment: when I do it this way, I get the following error: `angular.js:13550 ReferenceError: $interval is not defined`

Comment: did you inject the service as I said

Comment: you're using `$http` in your example, which means you must've injected the `$http` service.  `$interval` is a service that needs to be injected exactly the same way

Comment: This is not code I wrote but I am trying to extend the functionality for a team member

Comment: what would it look like when I injected `$http ` originally?

Comment: then you should look into angular dependency injection. or just look at how $http is injected

Comment: I will check it out. so `$interval` just needs to get injected?

Comment: Like this? `app.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filte` ?